# Setting the .prototype of a sub-class in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop

Given this bit of code:

```
var SuperClass = function(a, b) {
  this.a = a;
  this.b = b;
};

SuperClass.prototype.getA = function() {
  return this.a;
};

var SubClass = function(a, b, c) {
  SuperClass.call(this, a, b);
  this.c = c;
};
```

In order to initiate the `SubClass` prototype, most recommendations seem to be the following:

```
SubClass.prototype = new SuperClass();
```

It seems odd to me to create (instantiate) a new `SuperClass` object (with its own `a` and `b` properties) just to serve as the prototype for the `SubClass`.

This also works:

```
// anti-pattern
SubClass.prototype = SuperClass.prototype;
```

but it passes the `SuperClass.prototype` object by reference, so anything you add to the `SubClass.prototype` is also added to the `SuperClass.prototype`, because they are the same object.  This is not expected behavior in most cases.

QUESTION: Is there a way to achieve the proper prototyping without creating an instance of the `SuperClass` to serve as the `SubClass`'s base prototype?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under modern browsers:

```
SubClass.prototype = Object.create( SuperClass.prototype );
```

This lets you create an object with a defined [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Proto) *without* invoking the 'constructor' method of the parent class. For more details, read up on [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) (including a polyfill implementation for older browsers).

Seen in action:

```
function Foo(){ console.log("AHHH!"); }
Foo.prototype.foo = 42;
function Bar(){}
Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype);  // Note: no "AHHH!" shown
Bar.prototype.bar = 17;

// Showing that multi-level inheritance works
var b = new Bar;
console.log(b.foo,b.bar); //-> 42, 17

// Showing that the child does not corrupt the parent
var f = new Foo;          //-> "AHHH!"
console.log(f.foo,f.bar); //-> 42, undefined

// Showing that the inheritance is "live"
Foo.prototype.jim = "jam";
console.log(b.jim);       //-> "jam"
```

Answer (score 0):

Polyfill implementation for older browsers

```
// Create a new instance based on existing object
function object(o) {
  function F() {};
  F.prototype = o;
  return new F();
}

function inherit(subClass, superClass) {
  var prototype = object(superClass.prototype);
  prototype.constructor = subClass;
  subClass.prototype = prototype;
}
```

Although pass superClass.prototype leads to `F.prototype = superClass.prototype`, when object function return, the F function is not be accessed any more. In result, you are not able to get and change F.prototype.

Example:

```
function SuperClass() {};
function SubClass() {};

SuperClass.prototype.say = function() {console.log('super');};

var instance = object(SuperClass.prototype); //instance.__proto__ === SuperClass.prototype
instance.say();
```